# firewalld not blocking http and https access

Tags: linux, http, firewalld

I am running a httpd container on this machine, but http or https aren't enabled on firewalld. But I can still access the website from another machine that is on the same network. Why is this behavior? To my understanding, all the services that aren't listed in services section should be blocked, right ? So how can i access the website if it http isn't enbled ?

```
[root@VM2 ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens160
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client nfs ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
[root@VM2 ~]#
```

Comment: By container, you mean something along the lines of Docker or Podman, yes?

Comment: If it's docker it uses port forwarding and overrides your rules.

Comment: I am using podman and this is the command i am using :                                                                  

podman run -dt -p 8080:80/tcp docker.io/library/httpd:latest